# Como encontrar a ocorrência de valores inteiros iguais em um vetor?

Tags: java

Preciso encontrar frequência de idades em um vetor. Sei fazer isso quando o vetor é pequeno, mas não quando ele é grande. Considere o vetor abaixo:

```
int[] idade = {15,18,15,20,16,30,18,45,43,14,25,16,20};
```

Para esse vetor, eu poderia fazer uma busca sequencial para encontrar quantas pessoas tem a mesma idade:

```
for(i = 0; i < idade.length; i++){
        if(idade[i] == 14) i14++;
        if(idade[i] == 15) i15++;
        if(idade[i] == 16) i16++;
        /*if(...*/
}
```

Só que eu não estou conseguindo achar uma forma de encontrar a ocorrência de idades iguais quando o vetor tem mais de 1.000 posições. Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como isso pode ser feito?

Desde já muito obrigada!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minha resposta serve como uma alternativa à do @SeverMateus sem utilizar *streams* e totalizando com um array normal como se fosse um `HashMap`. Neste caso é simples de fazer pois a gama de valores possíveis para as idades é baixa.

Então a ideia começa com a criação de um array normal para a contagem das idades, assumindo um valor como máximo, para o caso pode ser `200`:

```
int[] contagemIdades = new int[200];
```

Depois a contagem é feita pegando em cada idade, e somando na posição correspondente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < idades.length; ++i){
    int idade = idades[i];
    contagemIdades[idade]++;
}
```

Após isto tem o vetor de contagens construído. Cada posição tem a quantidade de pessoas com essa idade, que será zero para os que não apareceram.

Para saber quais as idades que tem mais de uma pessoa, basta verificar se a contagem é superior ou igual a 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contagemIdades.length; ++i) {
    if (contagemIdades[i] >= 2){ //apenas as idades que tem mais que uma pessoa
        System.out.printf("Existem %d pessoas com %d anos de idade\n", contagemIdades[i], i);
    }
}
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/HbKbPD)

Saída:

```
Existem 2 pessoas com 15 anos de idade
Existem 2 pessoas com 16 anos de idade
Existem 2 pessoas com 18 anos de idade
Existem 2 pessoas com 20 anos de idade
```

Comment: Oi, @Isac! Muito obrigada por responder! Eu já consegui resolver! Na verdade, sua solução foi muito parecida com a minha! A diferença foi que fiz uma adaptação do algoritmo de classificação por contagem(counting sort). Mesmo assim, muito obrigada! ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Alternativamente a resposta do Guerra, poderá implementar de seguinte maneira usando apenas bibliotecas que já fazem parte do Java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestSorting {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(15,18,15,20,16,30,18,45,43,14,25,16,20);
    Map<Integer, Long> result =
            items.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()
                    )
            );

    Map<String, Long> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    //Sort a map and add to finalMap
    result.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue()
                    .reversed()).forEachOrdered(e -> finalMap.put(String.valueOf(e.getKey()), e.getValue()));

    System.out.println(finalMap);
    //Output: {16=2, 18=2, 20=2, 15=2, 25=1, 43=1, 45=1, 14=1, 30=1}
}
}
```

Caso quiser ver apenas o resultado de um membro:

```
    System.out.println(finalMap.get("18"));
    //Output: 2
```

Comment: Oi, @SeverMateus! Muito obrigada por responder! Eu já consegui resolver! Mesmo assim, muito obrigada! ^_^ Sua solução me ajudou em outra questão!

Answer (score 4):

Mais uma alternativa para solucionar este problema. Um pouco mais simples do que a solução apresentada por @SeverMateus.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> items = 
                 Arrays.asList(15,18,15,20,16,30,18,45,43,14,25,16,20);

        // TreeMap é inerentemente ordenado 
        Map<Integer, Integer> mapIdades = new TreeMap<>();

        // Computa os valores do map, caso seja primeira ocorrência,
        // adiciona 1, senão vai incrementando.
        items.forEach(idade -> 
                mapIdades.compute(idade, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : ++v));

        // Percorre valores computados
        mapIdades.forEach((idade, quantidade) -> 
                System.out.println(idade + " : " + quantidade));

    }
}
```

Por utilizar um Map você também poderá acessar os valores diretamente.

```
mapIdades.get(15); // 2
```

> Url para testar o código [>>> aqui <<<](https://repl.it/@IsraelMerljak/LinearKosherLinuxpc)

Comment: Oi! @IsraelMerljak, muito obrigada por responder! Eu já consegui resolver!  Mesmo assim, muito obrigada! ^_^ Sua solução também me deu ima ideia para outro problema! :-)